How to build a HeatMap on yandex maps in react via @pbe/react-yandex-maps
I'm trying to build a heatmap in yandex maps, if use vanilla JS there are no problems but in react-app, I'm not able to understand the documentation like how to import modules.
For Vanilla JS they provided the link of HeatMap to import it and use as modules
https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-heatmap?tab=readme-ov-file
But with react i'm using @pbe/react-yandex-maps but I'm not able to get the solution and no clear documentation provided for integration with React APP
I have tried using @pbe/react-yandex-maps npm module to work with Yandex map and it's working with normal map ploting but there is no clear documentation for integration with heatmap. I want to implement heatmap with yandex-maps
